# What is the best way to optimize a pipeline that requires functions that are written in C while only using PySpark?

Tags: c, azure, pyspark, databricks, etl

We are working on an ETL pipeline and expect a high throughput of data in the future. We received functions in C that we need to implement. Furthermore, we also have them in Python (using NumPy) and Matlab.

My suggestion was to compile the C code in Databricks and run it from there. However, our tech lead wonders if we can translate the functions using only PySpark.

Are there equivalents for np.diag(), np.abs(), np.cumsum(), and np.sum() in PySpark?

What would be the most efficient approach?

Edit: When trying to answer these questions myself, I ran several times into the suggestion that PySpark should be used for the basic operations, and when it comes to complex transformations on n-dimensional matrices, we should use Pandas and NumPy.
Am I missing something, or is this the optimal way to do it?

Edit2: The tech lead believes that it might be possible to use function from Sparks MLlib.

Final Edit: Spark has some libraries (mllib.linalg) that have functions that would be useful in solving this issue. The necessary methods like apply() from that library are not available in PySpark. Therefore, I have decided to use our NumPy code and create PySpark UDFs.

Comment: Yes we are using Azure

Comment: What are the sample code. can you add them.

Comment: For legal reasons, I cannot. All I could do was add the NumPy functions that we want to rebuild using PySpark.

Answer (score 0):

In PySpark, you can perform similar operations to np.diag(), np.abs(), np.cumsum(), and np.sum()

Here is the code:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

As can be seen in the below code pyspark can also be used to perform complex transformations in n-dimensional matrices.

[Implementation of the Spark technique in a matrix distributed computing algorithm](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/jisys-2022-0051/html?lang=en)

Here is the Transformation login Pyspark.
**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, DoubleType, StructType, StructField, IntegerType
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
data = [
    (1, [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [7.0, 8.0, 9.0]]),
    (2, [[10.0, 11.0, 12.0], [13.0, 14.0, 15.0], [16.0, 17.0, 18.0]]),
]

schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("matrix", ArrayType(ArrayType(DoubleType(), containsNull=True), containsNull=True), True)
])
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
**Basic operation**
abs_udf = udf(lambda matrix: [abs(x) for row in matrix for x in row], returnType=ArrayType(DoubleType()))
df_abs = df.withColumn("abs_matrix", abs_udf(col("matrix")))

**Complex transformation**
sqrt_udf = udf(lambda matrix: [x ** 0.5 for row in matrix for x in row], returnType=ArrayType(DoubleType()))
df_sqrt = df.withColumn("sqrt_matrix", sqrt_udf(col("matrix")))
df_abs.show(truncate=False)
df_sqrt.show(truncate=False)
```

[image]

- As per recommendation in official Pandas documenation it doesn’t
  support distributed processing. Hence, you would always need to
  increase the resources as your data size increases
- Also,pandas provides data structures for in-memory [analytics](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/scale.html?highlight=distributed%20processing), which makes using pandas to analyze datasets that are larger than memory datasets somewhat tricky. Even datasets that are a sizable fraction of memory become unwieldy, as some pandas operations need to
  make intermediate copies.

Comment: This is unfortunately not what I need.

Comment: @Lanorius94 So you do not want use np? you are only looking for the libraries (mllib.linalg) that have functions? is that right?

Comment: Yes, ideally it should only use PySpark and its libraries.

Comment: @Lanorius94 let me try that for you

Comment: Please, don't. Your first solution for diag() is completely wrong. You just selected the first column. Not only is this not the diagonal, but that diag() function from numpy can do a lot more than just get the main diagonal.